# TYPO3 broken after extension installation

Tags: typo3

My TYPO3 has broken after deactivating an extension (`direct_email`). I can't access my backend anymore and also I cannot deactivate the extension through the Installation tool.
This is the error that I got:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you type the code for easy debugging.

Comment: Edit typo3conf/PackageStates.php In this file, TYPO3 stores which extension will be loaded/is active. 
Which extension (and version) have you tried to install? And in which version of TYPO3? Normally, incompatible extensions give a warning in extensionmanager before you activate them.

Comment: I was able to find a solution deactivating the Extension in PckageStates then I logged into the backend and deleted the extension.

Comment: Please format your question to include the error message as text. This makes it easier to read and also easier to search for the error message in the future. The complete stack trace is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Errors after deactivating an extension sounds strange.

That only should occur if other extension do not have declared dependencies.

Aside from the `PackageStates.php` you should clean the caches. If you have no access to the Install_Tool (`typoe/install`) to clear the cache and check for broken extensions, you need to delete all caches in the cache-folders `/typoe3temp/var/Cache` (or similar, dependening on TYPO3 version)

You might give some more information about your installation (versions, kind of installation (composer), ..)